# При компиляции в VS получаю ошибку LNK2019

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, sdk

Решил поиграться с SDK одного симулятора 2006 года.

[image: иерархия]

Только написал функцию подключения/отключения, решил проверить работоспособность и получил от VS ошибку LNK2019.

[image: Ошибки]

Почитал про подобные ошибки и вроде как проблема в подключении библиотек, а в моём случае какая-то проблема с функцией main. Не работает даже так...

```
//#include <windows.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include "SimControl.h"

int main()
{
     //if (Open()) { ... }
     //system("pause");
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что-то мне кажется, что у вас проект оконного приложения, а оно требует не `main()`, а `WinMain()`...

Измените проект на консольное приложение.

Comment: Уфффф.... А я и позабыл что поставил в настройках Win32 project... Спасибо !

Answer (score 3):

> WinMain

Напишите `WinMain` вместо `main`, либо в опциях линкера укажите `/subsystem:console`.